# Bitcoin Solo Mining with bfgminer

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools, bfgminer

I am trying to do solo mining with bfgminer but it does not seems to be working

***./bfgminer --url 127.0.0.1:18443 --user test --pass test***

On bitcoind logs I can see the request logs

2018-05-14T10:36:25Z Received a POST request for / from 127.0.0.1:43312

2018-05-14T10:36:25Z ThreadRPCServer method=getwork user=test

2018-05-14T10:36:57Z Received a POST request for / from 127.0.0.1:43330

2018-05-14T10:36:57Z ThreadRPCServer method=getblocktemplate user=test

2018-05-14T10:36:57Z Received a POST request for / from 127.0.0.1:43332

2018-05-14T10:36:57Z ThreadRPCServer method=getwork user=test

**On bfgMiner I can see the following messages**

[2018-05-14 16:10:49] No servers were found that could be used to get work from.

[2018-05-14 16:10:49] Please check the details from the list below of the servers you have input

[2018-05-14 16:10:49] Most likely you have input the wrong URL, forgotten to add a port, or have not set up workers

[2018-05-14 16:10:17] Pool: 0  URL: http://127.0.0.1:18443  User: test  Password: test

[2018-05-14 16:10:17] Pool: 1  URL: 
http://localhost:8332/#getcbaddr#allblocks  User: test  Password: test

Any help

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you see are exactly what you get if you just start bitcoind without any proper configuration.

Did you make sure

- you started your bitcoind with the -server flag at all? Only that will prepare your bitcoin node to allow connections from external workers such as bfgminer.
- you waited for it to sync with the network? That can take up to some
  hours

Comment: This seems to be a good answer. However, please add some details, one-sentence answers are not well-received here.

Answer (score 0):

first if your url is not on a mining server your not going to be able to mine (and probabalistically there may be a way but anyway). it would look closer to -o stratum+tcp://emc2.suprnova.cc:3366 and the 127.0.0.1 should be an API address not the url.
second, for everyone who is looking for help with BFGMINER if you do not:
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1

then it probabalistically will not work as well. The export commands sync bfgminer immediatly to my gpu: ASUS GTX 1080 and starts hashing around 900 k/hs.